# Use NTFS HDD with FreeNAS

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, nas, import, windows-server

I'm making my old pc into a FreeNAS server to share my files in my home network. I have the server already up and running ok but I bumped into a problem when I tried to add 2 HDDs.

For some years I have collected all my files, cds, dvds in 2 external hdds of 3tb each, now I want to access these files without the need to connect each to the power and then to a usb port.

When I added them to the PC, Windows 7 showed all ok, but in freeNas - using the command to import NTFS drives - shows as if they have just 300GB. So I stopped the process fearing to lose it all...

Is there a way to add these drives without changing the filesystem? Is Windows Server a better solution? (if yes, will it show all my files?)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible your copy of FreeNas is so old it ignores GPTs (GUID partition Table)?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I`m using version 8.3

Comment: The current version is 9.1.1

Comment: I'm having the very same issue, but it shows my 3TB NTFS HDD (and my 8GB flash drives) as 768kb disks.

Comment: Even more people having very similar issues: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2081978

Comment: I upgraded to 9.1.1 and still no luck. Just 300GB are available...
But I tried in Windows Server 2008 R2, and the same problem. I think the problem is because I formatted it with the usb case, has anyone found a solution for this? I don't want to format 2 3TB HDD, I have both almost full.